# jQuery Multiply two values on drop down select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

Hi I have a bit of code which once you select drop value the price field updates

3 or more selected from drop down price = £10.99 each 2 price = £11.99 each 1 price = £12.99 each

```
jQuery(document).ready( function(){

        var map = [ '12.99', '11.99', '10.99' ];

        jQuery('#payslips-required').change(function(){

            var o = parseInt($(this).val()) < 3 ? jQuery(this).val()-1 : 2;

            jQuery('#price').val(map[o]).addClass('hidden');

        });

    });
```

Currently the above works but when I add a total field right next to it and amend the jQuery to work out the total, price x number selected

Here is the example in action http://jsfiddle.net/U92fq/1/ which works

but when I place the added code which is

```
var price = $('#price').val()   
            var quantity = $('#payslips-required').val()    
            var total = price * quantity;
            jQuery('#total').val(total).addClass('hidden');
```

Into into the original code does not work when it clearly does on the jsfiddle link provided both the price and total do not display.

Just can't see why it does not work.

Summary: Need to get the total to work.

Note: using this on Wordpress with Contact form 7 plugin can be seen here http://payslips4u.co.uk/order-monthly-payslips/

Comment: You didnt use semicolon after first and second line

Comment: Would it not be a good practice to parseFloat() your values?

Comment: The "Payslips Required" calculate-total-on-dropdown-change thing works for me at your http://payslips4u.co.uk/order-monthly-payslips/ page (and in your fiddle). What am I missing in your question?

Comment: @nnnnnn I updated the page from the answer KhanSharp provided. So its functional now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use semicolon end of each line

```
 jQuery('#price').val(map[o]).addClass('hidden');
            var price = $('#price').val();  
            var quantity = $('#payslips-required').val();   
            var total = price * quantity;
            jQuery('#total').val(total).addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: Why would that fix it? Semicolons are (arguably) good practice in JavaScript, but they're also (semi) optional - as you can see if you check the OP's fiddle, which works _without_ the semicolons.

Comment: @nnnnnn the answer he provided worked perfectly it was due to the missing semicolons

Comment: @addy88 - I just took another look at your (now fixed) page. The reason the semicolons fixed it is that you didn't have carriage returns after each statement, they were all on one long line (with some tabs between them). In my previous comment I said that semicolons are "(semi) optional" - one of the cases where they're _not_ optional is when you have more than one statement on the same line. (In your fiddle you did have the statements on separate lines, so that's why it worked without the semicolons.)

Answer (score 1):

Either use semicolon (;) at the end of each var or put one var with comma seperation

```
var price = $('#price').val(),  
    quantity = $('#payslips-required').val(),   
    total = price * quantity;
```